# the smoke _____ out from the chimney

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

Q. The smoke ____ out from the chimney.

a. left

b. rose

c. went

This question was asked recently in an exam. So which one of the options is the most appropriate option to be filled in the blank ?

Answer (score 1):

**b. rose**

From the [Online Oxford Collocation Dictionary](https://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=smoke#:%7E:text=Online%20OXFORD%20Collocation%20Dictionary&text=cloud%2C%20column%2C%20haze%2C%20pall,blow%20smoke%20in%20my%20face!), the entry in which being identical to that in the paper book *Oxford Collocations Dictionary for Students of English* (ISBN: 0-19-431243-7):

> SMOKE + VERB belch, billow, curl, drift, fill, pour, **rise** from/into

Also, in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), of all past-tense tense samples of SMOKE + VERB, "SMOKE ROSE" occurs most frequently with 165 instances. "SMOKE WENT" appears only 16 times, while "SMOKE LEFT" appears only 8 times.

What makes the above question somewhat awkward is the inclusion of the preposition "out." The phrase "the smoke rose *out* from" does not appear to be idiomatic. It does not appear in the collocation dictionary, and out of the 165 instances in the corpus, only one contains the preposition:

> [A thick column of black smoke rose out from inside the embassy compound.](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-202_162-57512847/official-libyan-insiders-may-have-aided-assault/) - CBS News

All other instances occur without the preposition:

> . . . plumes of smoke rose from the chimneys of factories . . . - Southwest Review, Vol. 103, Issue 4.